# How to make a gradient ring in java for android?

Tags: java, android, gradient

I am trying to draw out a ring with a nice gradient effect in java for an android application. I am trying to use the RadialGradient class found in android.graphics.RadialGradient, but it doesn't really do a gradient effect. I feel like it is just sort of mixing the 2 colors I subbed in for the color parameter, but I would like it to start from the first color I gave it and slowly transition itself to the second color in whatever direction it wants. The below is the code snippet for what I have tried.

```
paint.setColor(color);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
int[] colors = {Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 0), Color.argb(255, 219, 219, 7)};
Shader test = new RadialGradient(X, Y, radius, colors, null, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
paint.setShader(test);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(thickness);
```

Don't worry about the variables that I used that aren't shown how it was initialized. That part is not important.

Comment: Can you show me a sample image which you want to make?

Comment: Something like this ring, but I want the gradient on the outer half of the ring to fill the entire ring (for some reason it shows one gradient on the outer half and another gradient on the inner half). I created this particular ring in the picture using Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, along with a blue color 
http://postimg.org/image/bqvl7p4g5/

Comment: You probably want to paint on the fill instead of stroke, and then mask the fill to get the ring.